# Excel - Unequal lists with some corresponding data

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have two lists of data.  One is a master list it contains every product (in this case a person); say column A (worksheet 1) values 1 -250.  The second list is a weekly list and contains only some of the persons on the master list (Column A, Worksheet 2).  Another Column (B, Worksheet 2) has the data ( a refund) I want to return in Column A Worksheet 1 by the appropraite horizontal person ref.

So, if the fist entry in Column A Worksheet 2 (Cell A1) is person #6 how do I get the entry in Cell B1 (the refund due to person #6) to show up at the appropriate place on the master list i.e. (cell B6)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Vlookup`, In the master worksheet 1 in B2 (Row 1 for headers) write:
`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Weekly!$A$2:$B$4,2,FALSE),"")`

Drag the formula down 
A2 is your first value in the Master worksheet 1
Weekly!$A$2:$B$4 is your Data in Worksheet 2 Weekly Data change it to correspond to the last Row in it
$ to make the references fix in order to drag the formula down
2 to return the second column Refund in Worksheet 2
False to return the exact match of A2
Iferror to write empty "" in case A2 does not Exist in Worksheet 2

Comment: Thank you so much for this yass.  Apologies for the late response.  This is really useful.  Have a nice day!